# Reading temperature from LSM6DSO32

Tags: c, arduino

I would like to know what is the best way for reading temperature on this captor LSM6DSO32, here this the register
[image]
[image]

I'am working on Arduino with with an Atmel SAMD21 Cortex M0. Here, this is what I'll do

```
//reading register
Wire.beginTransmission(DSO_ADDRESS); 
Wire.write(0x20);                                      
Wire.endTransmission();   
Wire.requestFrom(DSO_ADDRESS, 14);

//get bytes, 14 beceause (temp,gyro,accel)
uint8_t buff[14];    
Wire.readBytes(buff, 14);

int16_t raw_t = buff[1] << 8 | buff[0];
float temperature = (raw_t / 256.0) + 25.0;
```

My question is, do you think this method is fine to get negative raw value ? For exemple if the temperature is 22° the raw value should be -700 average. Should I need to convert or cast something comes from the captor before assign `raw_t` ?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it was an typing error it’s buff not buffer sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, do you think this method is fine to get negative raw value ?

Code below likely "works", yet relies on implementation defined behavior.  (and UB if  `int` is 16-bit)

```
int16_t raw_t = buff[1] << 8 | buff[0];
```

Alternative that always works.

```
uint16_t uraw = ((uint16_t) buff[1]) << 8 | buff[0];
int16_t raw = (uraw & 0x8000u) ? uraw - 65536 : uraw;
```

---

Rather than `double math` and assigned to a `float`, use `float` math too.

```
// float temperature = (raw_t / 256.0) + 25.0;
float temperature = (raw_t / 256.0f) + 25.0f;
```

Likely slightly more correct in rounding.

```
float temperature = (raw_t + (int32_t)25*256) / 256.0f;
```

Comment: Ok great, this `(uraw & 0x8000u) ` is to test if the temperature is negative that's right?

Comment: @simon As temperature is a 16-bit 2's complement, code needs to convert the 2-byte unsigned of `buff[]` to an `int16_t`.  `uraw & 0x8000u` is true when the temperature is below 25C.